# When setting automatic updates installation, what about restarts?

Tags: 18.04, updates, desktop-environments

I set up automatic installation of (security) updates on a machine I gave away before quarantine.

[image]

Would notifications for restarting the computer appear to non-admin users, each time after updates which require a restart have been automatically downloaded and installed?

It's an Ubuntu Desktop installation I'm speaking about.

Answer (score 1):

You should not enable automatic rebooting if it is to be expected there are more users on a machine at that time. A reboot will happen without notifications. Apply for Livepatch if you want to update kernels without the need to reboot.

If you need a server to automatically reboot after updating use a fixed time. `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time` is intended for that and you can set it to reboot during your nighttime. And then inform your users that there will be downtime after updating. 
Otherwise users never know when it will happen.

Comment: So without Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time or something like that (where does one set that?), will the non-admin users not be prompted to reboot after security updates have been automatically applied thus having the restart needed for the updates defer possibly indefinitely? or will actually a reboot occur without asking them, after every unattended updates installation requiring a restart? I am asking this in the context of having set "Download and Install Automatically in the UI, like shown now in the question body, without any other tinkering or manual definitions being made.

Comment: It will reboot if you set for it to reboot after the update. No warnings.  And see `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` :) By default it does not reboot iirc so you might need to edit that too